# How do I initialize radius in this instance?

Tags: java, variables, initialization

I don't know how to initialize radius so that the user can input the radius when prompted to instead of having a set value to radius. I think I have everything else pretty much right here but I cannot for the life of me figure this out.
 What am I missing here? Please help

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class CircleCalc
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
   {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  double radius;
  double area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
  double circum = 2 * radius * Math.PI;
  DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");
  int choice;


  System.out.println("CIRCLE CALCULATOR MENU");
  System.out.println("1) Calculate the Area of a Circle");
  System.out.println("2) Calculate the CIrcumference of a Circle");
  System.out.println("3) Quit the Program");
  System.out.println("Make a selection by choosing a number:");
  choice = keyboard.nextInt();

  if (choice == 1)
  {
     System.out.println("What is the radius of the Circle?");
     radius = keyboard.nextInt();
     System.out.println(" The Area of the Circle with radius " + radius + " is " + area);
  }

  else if (choice == 2)
  {
     System.out.println("What is the radius of the Circle?");
     radius = keyboard.nextInt();
     System.out.println("The Circumference of the Circle with radius " + radius+ " is " + formatter.format(circum));
  }

  else if (choice == 3)
  {
  System.out.println("You have chosen to quit the program.");
  }

  else if (choice >3)
  {
  System.out.println("You have made an invalid selection.");
  }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem.

`Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  double radius;
  double area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
  double circum = 2 * radius * Math.PI;`

You have not initialized the radius value but at the same time you're using it in calculating area and circumference. Get the input from user first. Do this first `radius = keyboard.nextInt();`.

You can do the calculation after you have got the radius value from the user.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to define *functions* that calculate the circumference and the area for any radius (since you don't know the concrete radius at the point where you know how to calculate those)

```
public static double area(double radius) {
    return Math.PI * radius * radius;
}

public static double circum(double radius) {
    return 2 * radius * Math.PI;
}
```

Then later when you need to calculate the results you invoke these methods:

```
System.out.println(" The Area of the Circle with radius " + radius + " is " + area(radius));
```

And

```
System.out.println("The Circumference of the Circle with radius " + radius + " is " 
                   + formatter.format(circum(radius)));
```